# How to write a PowerShell script which auto increments a number by 1 every time it's run?

Tags: powershell, scripting, increment

I am looking for a PowerShell script which when the user clicks on from their desktop it increments a count by 1, keeps a record and when the user next clicks the script it increments from last number with formatting of 000000.

So when the user launches the script it becomes 000001, next time it'll be 000002,000010... and so on.

I have tried the below but it's not seem to be working, I am not to shell scripting. I am also not sure how to save the previous run, so next time it increments from the last number.

```
$counter = 0;
$counter++
```

Comment: Just create a File and read it at the start of each execution

Answer (score 2):

here is some example to create a file and format the numbers. Remember that leading zeros are only possible in a string. (place `$counter = $counter++` at will)

```
$path = "D:\test\text.txt"
# Test if the file exists
if ( (Test-Path $path) ) {
    # read file
    $content = Get-Content $path
    # convert string to int
    $counter = [int]$content
}else{
    $counter = 0
}
$counter++
# create a string with leading zeros
$countString = "{0:d6}" -f ($counter)

# end of your script
# save to file
$countString | Out-File $path
```

`"{0}" -f $var` will format the variable in a stringa specific way. See [here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) for a list how you can format the variables. Add more variables to a string like this: `"{0} , {1} , {2}" -f $var1,$var2,$var3`

An alternative would be to manipulate the .ps1 file itself and write the number in the scriptfile... But i wouldn't realy recommand that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be creating the file.

Comment: try an other path. On my pc I tested it with   `$countString | Out-File "D:\test\text.txt"`

Comment: That's working now, how can I make it increment number everytime it's clicked. I added $counter++ but it only increments once, saves it and doesn't increment again. Can I also check ask for my knowledge what does $countString = "{0:d6}" -f ($counter) do please?

Comment: @AdamKhan Added the requested infos in the answere.

Comment: It saves a file if not there with 000000 but with subsequent runs it does not increment the value.

Comment: Thanks, that's working. I am trying to understand why it wasn't before with $counter = $counter++. As this means set the counter value to what it is 1 from my understanding?

Comment: That confused me too. Somehow `$i = $i++` replaces `$i` with the value of `$i` after incrementing `$i`. So the value won't change...

Comment: I see, that's strange. Thanks for the help really appreciate it.